# Passing variables in JSX

Tags: javascript, jsx, use-state

I have a function where im sending a fetch request and storing the returned data using `setStockData` the basic breakdown of the code is below.

```
  function LoggedIN(){
      const [stockData, setStockData] = useState([]); // Data from the API search

       // 
      // Set the stockData from a fetch in this area 
     //

      return (
        <Graphdraw /> 
      );
    }
```

The `stockData` variable looks basically like this once its set.

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-03-19T14:00:00.000Z",
    "symbol": "AAL",
    "name": "American Airlines Group",
    "open": 11.6,
    "high": 12.16,
    "low": 10.01,
    "close": 10.29,
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-03-18T14:00:00.000Z",
    "symbol": "AAL",
    "name": "American Airlines Group",
    "open": 14.24,
    "high": 14.28,
    "low": 10.17,
    "close": 11.65,
  }
]
```

I want to pass `stockData` into the `<Graphdraw />` so that i can access it like the following

```
function Graphdraw(props){

  for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++){
    console.log(props[i].low);
  }

}
```

So far ive read a few posts and looked at the jsx pages but can't seem to get it to pass correctly. How do i pass `stockData` into `<Graphdraw />` and am i accessing it correctly in the `function Graphdraw (props)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this?

```
function LoggedIN(){
  const [stockData, setStockData] = useState([]); // Data from the API search

   // 
  // Set the stockData from a fetch in this area 
 //

  return (
    <Graphdraw stockData={stockData} /> 
  );
}

function Graphdraw(props){
  for (let i = 0; i < props.stockData.length; i++){
     console.log(props.stockData[i].low);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass it like this:

```
return (
    <Graphdraw stockData={stockData} /> 
);
```

Within `Graphdraw`, you access it as `props.stockData`, although it's common to use destructuring in the parameter list so you can just use `stockData`:

```
function Graphdraw({stockData}) {
    // ...use `stockData` here...
}
```

Details in [the tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props).